# How to change Account Kit api version in the developer dashboard

Tags: facebook, account-kit

How do I change my Account Kit API version setting in the facebook developer dashboard.  I see one of my apps has v1.0 and the other app has v1.1

I'd like to keep them both consistent with the same version.

Comment: You don’t change it, because it is only the _minimum_ API version your app can use (as the tooltip behind the question mark already explains.)

Comment: Why would they different between two applications?  What determines this version number?

Comment: The point in time when you created the app id ... the current API version at that time is the lowest your app can ever use.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very easy process. Just go to:

`developer.facebook.com >> select your App >> settings >>app version....(See the link)`

http://prntscr.com/nluyc3

You can't change the app version facebook make the version latest by default.

Thanks...